# Accessing json data issue

Tags: javascript, json, object

I know there are many questions about this issue but  my problem is different  I managed to get the data outside of $.getJSON()  but I couldn't access them

```
 var country = {} ; 

     $.getJSON('https://freegeoip.net/json/', function (code) { 

        country.config = code ;

  });

console.log(country);
```

I will get these information

> {}config: {ip: "**********", country_code: "LB", country_name:
>   "Lebanon", region_code: "06", region_name: "Beirut", …}**proto**:
>   Object

if I try to access them like this

> country.config.country_code

I will get this error

> fdgdfgd:643 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'country_code' of
>   undefined

I can't even access this one

> country.config

How can I get the data from this object ?

Comment: I changed the title  I hope you read whole thing before  mark it as duplicated. I managed to return the response I want to access it now

Comment: Your question is a 100% duplicate. Your code *cannot* work. You need to tackle and understand asynchronous calls. Your problem is not special or different.

Comment: But console.log printed the data outside getJSON function therefor it works fine,  I got this solution from another answer  and it's the simplest one. I just want to know how to access these data  I can only print country  I can't access further

Comment: No, read the other two duplicates as well. This. Can. Not. Work.

Comment: @deceze only the [1st](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/673991) linked duplicate is the same issue. The other two are just confusing things. The 2nd seems to be about a browser bug and the 3rd is an unusual aspect of console.log() interactivity.

Comment: @user3763103 because `console.log(country)` executes before `country.config = code`.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone The other dupes pertain to why OP is seeing the behavior they do.

Comment: @deceze thank you, I see it now. Two time warps.